# Folder upload Electron

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, file-upload, electron, electron-packager

I am using the input with the directory attributes for folder upload that when i am using in Chrome gives me as a result an array of files and information about them [image: Input result for Chrome]

But when I am using the electron build with the same input it gives me an object with only the local path name and some additional stuff.

[image: Input result for Electron]

This is really bad for me as I am trying to loop through the files in the folders and only accept those that have certain exceptions.
How can I achieve that with something that is compatible for both Chrome and Electron? I thought Electron was based on Chrome?

I am using ReactJS on the frontend.
Thank you